# Is there any way to execute intermediate operations in a stream depending on a Predicate?

Tags: java, java-stream

The question may sound way obvious, but I haven't been able to find any intermediate operations that executes on a stream depending on a `Predicate`. For instance, imagine we have a stream of String and we want to append "-short" to the string if it has less than 5 characters and "-long" otherwise.

The thing is that, as far as I know, I'm forced to apply    `.filter(Predicate<String> predicate)`, which makes me unable to keep the whole stream, or mapping the stream somehow: `Map<List<String>, Boolean>`.

Is there any way I can execute such operations depending on Predicate or some conditional structure?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that by making the mapping function itself return different result based on a condition.

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaaa");
stream
    .map(str -> str.length() < 5 ? str + "-short" : str + "-long")
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```